# Upgrade to Laravel 4.1 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I believe I have all my dependencies ready for 4.1, but I get the following errors when I use composer update:

Generating autoload files

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error:

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error:

My composer file is as follows:

{

```
"require": {

    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "jasonlewis/basset": "dev-master",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "dev-master",
            "frozennode/administrator": "dev-master",
            "bllim/datatables": "*",
            "scubaclick/mandrill": "dev-develop"
},
"require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "1.8.*",
    "way/generators": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/Acme/Apis/v1"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Acme" : "app/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

}

Comment: Manually run `php artisan optimize` to see the errors.

Comment: I did but I get nothing, it looks like artisan is not running at all in its current state. When at 4.0 I could get all the commands when I ran 'php artisan'. Now it is not executing.

Comment: Solved! It looks like it was the redis configuration and the routes that need to be changed in the upgrade. The upgrade instructions should say that this error occurs in the upgrade process until all steps complete.

Comment: @user3061986 I think it is in the instructions: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/upgrade.md

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will get this kind of errors if you don't have proper route to any of your class file in **autoload_classmap.php** file from **composer directory** and you are still using that file.

This can be solved by executing **php artisan dump-autoload** file before using your new file.

If you're already using that file than please comment that part, run php artisan dump-autoload and then uncomment those line which were commented earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You would have needed to do `composer update --no-scripts` to update all your composer files without running the artisan commands; the reason for this is until composer has finished artisan would be broken by the upgrading and the default composer.json file has the command `php artisan clear-compiled` set to run before the vendor folder is updated.

If all else fails then delete your vendor directory and the composer.lock file and then run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

At the time the upgrade process required me to take that post compile out, run it, then do it again. I did finally get it to work, but it was not smooth.