# Cannot update Laravel 4.0 to 4.1 or even 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Here is the error I am getting:

```
composer update laravel/framework

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1

```
- Installation request for filp/whoops == 1.0.7.0 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.7].
- laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.11 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.12 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.13 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.14 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.15 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.16 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.17 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.18 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.19 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.20 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.21 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.22 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.23 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.24 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.25 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.26 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.27 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.28 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.29 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- laravel/framework v4.1.30 requires filp/whoops 1.0.10 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.10].
- Conclusion: don't install filp/whoops 1.0.10
- laravel/framework v4.1.0 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.1 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.10 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.2 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.3 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.4 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.5 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.6 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.7 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.8 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- laravel/framework v4.1.9 requires filp/whoops 1.0.9 -> satisfiable by filp/whoops[1.0.9].
- Conclusion: don't install filp/whoops 1.0.9
- Installation request for laravel/framework 4.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
```

I tried with 4.3 and got an error too. What can I do?

```
{
"name": "andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site",
"description": "Laravel 4 Starter Site",
"keywords": ["laravel","Starter Site"],
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Andrew Elkins",
        "homepage": "http://www.andrewelkins.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master",
    "jasonlewis/basset": "dev-master",
    "robclancy/presenter": "dev-develop",
    "j20/php-uuid": "dev-master",
    "greggilbert/recaptcha": "*",
    "league/oauth2-server": "2.1.x",
    "league/oauth2-client": "dev-master",
    "zetacomponents/database": "1.4.6",
    "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "1.0.x"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "dev-master",
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
    "summerstreet/woodling": "0.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [

        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/library",
        "app/models",
        "app/presenters",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/library"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: `Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension` Install the mcrypt extension on your machine

Comment: It is installed. It's just composer being stupid.

Comment: You see it as nothing to do with it. It's my Mac that was not getting the right PHP. Now it is. I am still getting the problem.

Comment: Who put -1? If you have the solution can you share it? Thank you.

Comment: How could people help you? you just blame it on composer without even providing `composer.json`?

Comment: Composer has always hung for me in an instance where I attempted to DL laravel. It completely made me _not_ use the framework.

Comment: This is not the first time. It's always like this. Well different problems. There is always something... And always takes for ever to figure out what is the source of the problem and most of the times I never figure out what it is. The problem is that I am stuck with this framework for the time being. But @RPM you're right, I am leaving that framework I have had enough.

Comment: I thought composer was written in C, but then saw the github repo it's written in PHP no wonder it hangs. They need to really fix it.

Comment: I just tried something else and it does not work. Every single time I try to do anything I run into problems.

Comment: Just to verify, @jnbdz, have you followed the [upgrade steps](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1)?

Comment: You might also want to see if [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20354763/899126) help

Answer (score 0):

Found the same problem. Open composer.lock and check all dependencies of "laravel/framework", then delete the folders one by one and use composer update again. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you change the version of laravel in your composer.json
- remove all the vendor folder
- do composer update

if it fails, post you response here again.

it simply says that laravel don't use specific version of whoops.